# Undefined is not a function javascript error

Tags: javascript, html

Im really bad at javascript and my code doesnt work for some reason. I get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function js.js:2
cleaning js.js:2
onblur (index):11
```

js.js

```
function cleaning() {
    var str = document.getElementByName("fitas").innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/^.+?(<url=[^>]+>).+$/, '$1');
    document.getElementByName("fitas").innerHTML = str;
}
```

html

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="js.js"></SCRIPT>
<center>        
<form method="post" action="check.php">
<h1>Enter your fit:</h1><br />

<textarea style="width: 500px; height: 400px;" name="fitas" class="text" placeholder="Input your fitting here" onblur="cleaning()"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="check" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `getElementsByName` note the **`s`**, `document.getElementByName` is not defined.

That would get you a nodeList, so

```
function cleaning() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByName("fitas")[0];

    elem.value = elem.value.replace(/^.+?(<url=[^>]+>).+$/, '$1');
}
```

Also, the way you're typing the script tag was popupar in the nineties, these days it's all lowercase, and you don't need a language attribute, and in HTML5 you don't really need a type attribute either.

Comment: still doesnt work, getting same error

Comment: @Mantas7776 - change innerHTML to value, see update

Answer (score 0):

```
function cleaning() {
    var str = document.getElementByName("fitas").innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/^.+?(<url=[^>]+>).+$/, '$1');
    document.getElementByName("fitas").innerHTML = str;
}
```

SHOULD BE

```
function cleaning() {
    var str = document.getElementsByName("fitas").innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/^.+?(<url=[^>]+>).+$/, '$1');
    document.getElementByName("fitas").innerHTML = str;
}
```

**not getElementByName but getElement[S]ByName**

note S

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="js.js"></SCRIPT>
```

Comment: While this is good advice in general, this isn't the main issue -- (pretty much) all browsers still recognise the legacy `language` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's getElementsByName not getElementByName

Also, it returns an array, so try this:

```
function cleaning() {
    var str = document.getElementsByName("fitas")[0].innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/^.+?(<url=[^>]+>).+$/, '$1');
    document.getElementsByName("fitas")[0].innerHTML = str;
}
```

edit: I made a mistake on the last line - it's fixed now.

Comment: still getting same error :/

Comment: I made a mistake in the code. It's fixed now.